# Problem with native queries when there are two data sources in the project

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

When the project had one data source, native queries ran fine, now when there are two data sources, hibernate cannot determine the schema for receiving native queries, non-native queries work fine.

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
  flyway:
    test:
      testLocations: classpath:/db_test/migration,classpath:/db_test/migration_test
      testSchemas: my_schema
    locations: classpath:/db_test/migration
    baselineOnMigrate: true
    schemas: my_schema
  jpa:
    packages-to-scan: example.example1.example2.example3.example4
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
      hibernate.format_sql: false
      hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 50
      hibernate.order_inserts: true
      hibernate.order_updates: true
      hibernate.generate_statistics: false
      hibernate.prepare_connection: false
      hibernate.default_schema: my_schema
      org.hibernate.envers:
        audit_table_prefix: log_
        audit_table_suffix:
      hibernate.javax.cache.uri: classpath:/ehcache.xml
      hibernate.cache:
        use_second_level_cache: true
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.SingletonEhcacheRegionFactory
      hibernate:
        connection:
          provider_disables_autocommit: true
          handling_mode: DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION
    hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
#    todo:
    open-in-view: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

  #database connections
  read-only:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:6432/db
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
      configuration:
        pool-name: read-only-pool
        read-only: true
        auto-commit: false
        schema: my_schema
  read-write:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:6433/db
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
      configuration:
        pool-name: read-write-pool
        auto-commit: false
        schema: my_schema
```

**Datasources config:**

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.read-write.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties readWriteDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.read-only.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties readOnlyDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.read-only.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource readOnlyDataSource(DataSourceProperties readOnlyDataSourceProperties) {
        return readOnlyDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.read-write.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource readWriteDataSource(DataSourceProperties readWriteDataSourceProperties) {
        return  readWriteDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RoutingDataSource routingDataSource(DataSource readWriteDataSource, DataSource readOnlyDataSource) {
        RoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceType.READ_WRITE, readWriteDataSource);
        dataSourceMap.put(DataSourceType.READ_ONLY, readOnlyDataSource);
        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(readWriteDataSource);

        return routingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor dialectProcessor() {

        return new BeanPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) {
                    ((HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) bean).getJpaDialect().setPrepareConnection(false);
                }
                return bean;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Routing data sources**

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DataSourceTypeContextHolder.getTransactionType();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTargetDataSources(Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources) {
        super.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
        afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

**depending on the type of transaction readOnly or not, the datasource is selected**

```
public class DataSourceTypeContextHolder {
    private static final ThreadLocal<DataSourceType> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setTransactionType(DataSourceType dataSource) {
        contextHolder.set(dataSource);
    }

    public static DataSourceType getTransactionType() {
        return contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearTransactionType() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TransactionAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(transactional) && execution(* *(..))")
    public void setTransactionType(Transactional transactional) {
        if (transactional.readOnly()) {
            DataSourceTypeContextHolder.setTransactionType(DataSourceType.READ_ONLY);
        } else {
            DataSourceTypeContextHolder.setTransactionType(DataSourceType.READ_WRITE);
        }
    }

    @AfterReturning("@annotation(transactional) && execution(* *(..))")
    public void clearTransactionType(Transactional transactional) {
        DataSourceTypeContextHolder.clearTransactionType();
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE my_table SET lock_until = timezone('utc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + cast(? as interval), locked_at = timezone('utc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), locked_by = ? WHERE my_table.name = ? AND my_table.lock_until <= timezone('utc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "my_table" does not exist
  Позиция: 8
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:883)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:321)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:326)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.lambda$execute$0(JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.execute(JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.java:115)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.updateRecord(JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.java:81)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.support.StorageBasedLockProvider.doLock(StorageBasedLockProvider.java:91)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.support.StorageBasedLockProvider.lock(StorageBasedLockProvider.java:65)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor328.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.lock(Unknown Source)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.executeWithLock(DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.java:63)
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.aop.MethodProxyScheduledLockAdvisor$LockingInterceptor.invoke(MethodProxyScheduledLockAdvisor.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at example1.example2.example3.example3.example3.example3.example3.scheduler.ExampleContentSheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$631d68e1.loadData(<generated>)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor320.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "my_table" does not exist
```

when I change the native query and specify the schema before the table name, the query processes normally :
UPDATE my_schema.my_table SET lock_until = timezone('utc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + cast(? as interval), locked_at = timezone('utc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), locked_by = ? WHERE my_schema.my_table.name = ? AND my_schema.my_table.lock_until <= timezone('utc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Thanks!

Comment: A different approach is the dblink for postgres. You could use one db only with your valid native queries. More infos here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-connect.html plus:you have full native speed.

Answer (score 0):

The BadSqlGrammarException you get is because the table 'my_table' is not found in the predefined schema. As you said, modifying the native query with the schema, explicitly specifying `my_schema.my_table`, it's working because you're telling exactly where to find that table.

When you have multiple data sources, each datasource can have a different schema and Hibernate wouldn't know which schema to search for the `my_table` if you don't specify it explicitly.

In your application.yaml, you have defined a default schema as `my_schema` using the property `hibernate.default_schema`:

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate.default_schema: my_schema
```

But this option applies only for Hibernate specific code and it does not apply when you are running native SQL queries because Hibernate can't apply its features as the query is specific to the database and must be executed as it is.

In the case of native queries, you should always specify the schema in the query itself. That's how Hibernate knows which table to use from which schema.